# Sending with PHP PEAR Mail fails using SSL+AUTH

Tags: php, email, ssl, pear

Using code similar to below: On my server side I get an error that seems to imply it is trying use a certificate rather than the user/pass I'm providing (also below). Anyone else seen that, and have you gotten it to work? I've tried googling the error but I seem to just get a bunch of irrelevant results. Linux/PHP7.2.5 (also fails on PHP5.4.20) BUT seems to work just fine under Windows/PHP7

> SSL_accept error from mail.XXXXXX.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 0
>   warning: TLS library problem: 20353:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1293:SSL alert number 48:

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";
 $port = 465;

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => 'PLAIN',
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the error message is

> unknown ca

which means "certificate is signed by an unknown certificate authority".

Check if the root CA list is up to date on the machine.

Comment: Ya but... there's no certificate involved. It's a user/pass connection.

Comment: `$host = "ssl://` means ssl/tls, means certificates